# How to pass v-model value to child's child component in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, v-model

how can I pass the v-model value from parent component to child's child component?

Parent component

```
<ChildElement v-model="name" />

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const name = ref('Nagisa')
  }
};
</script>
```

Child component

```
<AnotherChildComponent :value="value"/>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue']
};
</script>
```

AnotherChild component

```
<input :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" />

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  setup() {
  }
};
</script>
```

This works when I want to update parent component name value from AnotherChild component, however the default name value ('Nagisa') will not render in AnotherChild component just stays empty string in input.

Vuex is not option, I want to directly pass from parent component. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to pass any component attributes, you need to usethe exact name you entered in props object of child component. For example..

In *AnotherChild* component's setup, you have prop with name *modelValue*, with default value of empty string.

```
props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
},
```

But, in its parent element, ChildComponent, you pass the value with name *value*,

```
<AnotherChildComponent :value="value"/>
```

which will not work, because you do not have any prop named *value* in *AnotherChild* Component, and so modelValue uses its default value of empty string. You need to pass the value as attribute with the prop name, like this:

```
<AnotherChildComponent :model-value="value"/>
```

This applies also to *Child* Component's parent and so on...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was passing because vue 2 worked this way but I needed to change to model-value as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are very welcome!